# How to pass single dot value to path variable in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

How to pass single dot (.) value  to path variable springboot. When we pass dot value to path variable, getting http 405 error.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/example/{value:.+}")
```

By this line of code the dot will be treated as part of value.

See [this article for reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-pathvariable-dot)

Comment: I have tried above,but no luck. Can u pls help me  to get path variable value to allow single dot value